# Como agregar un boton de impresion a un reporte personalizado ya existente Odoo v11

Tags: odoo, openerp

cree hace un tiempo un reporte personalizado en el modulo de contabilidad un reporte personalizado.. que funciona bastante bien.. ahora lo que me gustaria hacer es agregarle un button en el header como el que tiene por defecto pero que este relacionado con mi reporte personalizado

```
<report
        id="account_invoices"
        model="account.invoice"
        string="Factura pre-impresa"
        report_type="qweb-pdf"
        name="custom_report_module.report_custom_template"
        file="custom_report_module.report_custom_template"
        attachment_use="True"
        attachment="(object.state in ('open','paid')) and
            ('INV'+(object.number or '').replace('/','')+'.pdf')"
    />
```

Asi es como llamo a mi reporte que aparece en la lista desplegable, despues lo que intento es agregarle el button pero simplemente no me funciona

```
<record id="account_invoices_button" model="account.invoice">
        <field name="name">account.invoice.form</field>
        <field name="model">account.invoice.form</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="custom_report_module.report_custom_template"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <button name="check_confirm_bank" position="after">
                <button name="print_bank_statement" string="Print Statement" type="object" help="Print in Pdf"/>
            </button>
        </field>

    </record>
```

Alguna ayuda???